# ErrorException Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::company does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem using Laravel Framework. I am trying to build a simple`@if`and`@else`function.

> ErrorException Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::company does not exist

Here is my code for my layout app.blade.php

```
@if(auth::user())
      {{auth::user()->name}}
    @else
      {{auth::company()->name}}
    @guest
    <p>i am here</p>
    @endguest
```

Comment: Can you try : `Auth::user()->company->name`?

Comment: Am guessing the issue is with `company` just to put it clear you are saying if the user is not authenticated then get authenticated company name. is that the case?

Comment: Where you defined the company() function? I can't find it in the laravel Auth system.

Answer (score 0):

`{{auth::user()->name}}` does work because `user()` will return the currently logged in auth model

`{{auth::company()->name}}` doesn't work because `company()` is not a default function for the auth facade.

You can use `return view('example')->with('company' => Company::first());` in your controller to be able to use `{{ $company->name }}` in your code. This is assuming that the Company model exists and you just want the first one to display.